# Conversion to DateTime method cutting off list rendering (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, datetime, erb

I'm working with an ApplicationHelper method that translates Time objects into 'humanized' time measurements in my view:

```
def humanize_seconds s
    if s.nil?
      return ""
    end
    if s > 0
      m = (s / 60).floor
      s = s % 60
      h = (m / 60).floor
      m = m % 60
      d = (h / 24).floor
      h = h % 24
      w = (d / 7).floor
      d = d % 7
      y = (w / 52).floor
      w = w % 52
      output = pluralize(s, "second") if (s > 0)
      output = pluralize(m, "minute") + ", " + pluralize(s, "second") if (m > 0)
      output = pluralize(h, "hour") + ", " + pluralize(m, "minute") if (h > 0)
      output = pluralize(d, "day") + ", " + pluralize(h, "hour") if (d > 0)
      output = pluralize(w, "week") + ", " + pluralize(d, "day") if (w > 0)
      output = pluralize(y, "years") + ", " + pluralize(w, "week") if (y > 0)

      return output
    else
      return pluralize(s, "second")
    end
  end
```

It's working great, but I'm running into an issue when translating the end result of a method designed to list time intervals in a specified location:

RFIDTag.rb:

```
def time_since_first_tag_use
    product_selections.none? ? "N/A" : Time.now - product_selections.order(staged_at: :asc).first.staged_at
  end
```

Product.rb:

```
def first_staged_tag
  rfid_tags.map { |rfid| rfid.time_since_first_tag_use.to_i }.join(", ")
end
```

View: (html.erb):

Putting the value out there works, and lists the values as `first_staged_tag` is meant to do, but it only does so in seconds:

```
 <% @products.order(created_at: :desc).each do |product| %>
   <td><%= product.name %></td> #Single product name
   <td><%= product.first_staged_tag %></td> list, i.e. #40110596, 40110596, 39680413, 39680324
 <%end%>
```

While converting in the usual way `<td><%= humanize_seconds(product.first_staged_tag) %></td>`, as has worked for single values gives this error:

```
comparison of String with 0 failed
Extracted source (around line #88):              
86      return ""
87    end
88    if s > 0
89      m = (s / 60).floor
90      s = s % 60
91      h = (m / 60).floor
```

Meanwhile, trying to apply that method in the Product model `first_staged_tag` method generates a NoMethod error on `humanize_seconds`. How can I get my list of times to recognize the time conversion?

An iteration of everything tried is in the comments.

Comment: It looks like `s` is a strong containing a list of numbers instead of being just a number. You'll need to pick the number you want to use and just pass that in.

Comment: Yeah, I can get it to report only one number okay a similar method. Can I not somehow pass to one of the earlier model stages? I get method errors every time I try it, but I'm not sure how else to get there.

Comment: I dunno your code or your objective. You could probably peel off first or last number in the comma list and use that. But maybe you want to sort and use smallest or largest. I'm just looking at that "comparison of String with 0 failed" message.

Comment: objective is to get `40110596, 40110596, 39680413, 39680324` to list in `# years, #months, #weeks, #days`.  I have an alternate method that just grabs the first one of the list, but I want to grab the whole list; I've managed it for a few other items in the same view row.

Comment: Oh, if you want them all, write code to iterate over them.

Comment: Yes, I do that in the map and join in the `Product` model. It only fails when I try to convert the time to something more readable.

Comment: The map step is what makes it a string. Maybe you want to put the conversion in there? `humanize_seconds( rfid.time_since_first_tag_use.to_i )`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how I was getting the NoMethodError issue mentioned at the end there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! The tags had to be mapped in the Product model, and converted there:

```
#Product.rb 
def first_staged
    rfid_tags.map { |rfid| rfid.time_since_first_tag_use.to_i }
  end
```

Then iterated over *again* in the view as a whole:

```
<%= product.first_staged.map {|time| humanize_seconds(time) }.join(", ") %>
```